# How do I query a user's details from Firebase database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is how the data is structured. So I wan't to query user and query equal to the uid of the user.

[image: poopy]

```
let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user")

queryRef.queryEqualToValue(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in


        self.userDict.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)
        print(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.searchTableView.reloadData()
            print(self.userDict)
            SwiftLoader.hide()


            queryRef.removeAllObservers()

        })
    })
```

I am able to print the values of first name and last name but not address or image. Also can't save as NSDictionary. If I take out queryEqualToValue it works fine, but I get the values of all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user")
queryRef.child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
   print(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)
}
```

Comment: Good answer! It's an important thing to keep in mind with Firebase (and most any NoSQL database): direct access is faster/more scalable than a query.